# Flask-Admin - How can I create a custom InlineModelForm that generates a dynamic field per related db record

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm trying to create dynamic inline fields based on a model (`Parameter`) and populate the corresponding dynamically-created field with the value from the related `ParameterValue` model.

Where I'm stuck is I don't know how to intercept the `ParameterValue` instance during the inline form construction to only create a single field based on the values in the `ParameterValue.parameter` relationship (`[name, type, display_name, is_required, help_text]`)

`Parameter.name` is the variable name for the form field
`Parameter.type` determines what type of field it should be
`Parameter.display_name` is the label used on the form
`Parameter.is_required` determines if the required property should be added to the field
`Parameter.help_text` is passed as the "description" kwarg and rendered below the input

With my current code, each of the inline form fields have the columns of the `ParameterValue` model (the typical behavior of an inline form field).

Can anyone provide some insight on how to make the below MWE code produce 2 fields (one string field and one boolean field) based on the `Account.reporter_fields` relationship?

## MVE

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_admin.model.form import InlineFormAdmin
from flask_admin.form.fields import Select2TagsField
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableList
from wtforms.fields import BooleanField, IntegerField, StringField
from wtforms.validators import Optional, Required

app = Flask("StackOverflow MVE")
app.config.update({
    "SECRET_KEY": "NOTASECRET",
    "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI": "sqlite:///:memory:",
    "SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS": False
})
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


FIELD_TYPES = {
    "str": StringField,
    "int": IntegerField,
    "bool": BooleanField,
    "list": Select2TagsField
}


def generate_field(parameter):
    """Generates a dynamic field based on properties stored in the parameter table.

    :param parameter: The :class:`app.models.Parameter` used to derive field properties.
    :return: A form field based on the properties of ``parameter``.
    """
    field = FIELD_TYPES[parameter.type]
    kwargs = dict(
        label=parameter.display_name,
        description=parameter.help_text or "",
        validators=[Required() if parameter.is_required else Optional()],
        filters=[lambda value: value or None]
    )

    if parameter.type == "bool":
        del kwargs["validators"]
        del kwargs["filters"]
        kwargs["default"] = parameter.is_required
    elif parameter.type == "list":
        del kwargs["filters"]

    return field(**kwargs)


class ParameterValue(db.Model):
    """Assigns a value to a parameter and assigns the parameter to an entity."""
    __tablename__ = "parameter_value"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parameter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("parameter.id"), nullable=False)
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("account.id"), nullable=False)
    str_value = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    int_value = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    bool_value = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True)
    list_value = db.Column(MutableList.as_mutable(db.JSON), nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Explicit __init__ added to accommodate hybrid_property."""
        self.parameter = kwargs.pop("parameter")
        for kwarg, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, kwarg, value)

    @hybrid_property
    def value(self):
        return getattr(self, f"{self.parameter.type}_value")

    @value.setter
    def value(self, new_value):
        setattr(self, f"{self.parameter.type}_value", new_value)

    @value.deleter
    def value(self):
        setattr(self, f"{self.parameter.type}_value", None)


class Parameter(db.Model):
    """Defines the properties of a dynamic parameter."""
    __tablename__ = "parameter"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    reporter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("reporter.id"), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(
        db.Enum("str", "int", "bool", "list", name="parameter_type_enum"),
        nullable=False,
        default="str"
    )
    display_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True, default=None)
    is_required = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    help_text = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True, default=None)

    values = db.relationship("ParameterValue", backref="parameter")


class Reporter(db.Model):
    """The parent entity."""
    __tablename__ = "reporter"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    module = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    parameters = db.relationship("Parameter", backref="reporter", lazy="dynamic", cascade="all, delete")
    accounts = db.relationship("Account", backref="reporter", cascade="all, delete")


class Account(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "account"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    reporter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("reporter.id"), nullable=False)
    client_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    reporter_fields = db.relationship("ParameterValue", lazy="dynamic", backref="account")


class ParameterInlineForm(InlineFormAdmin):
    """Kind of stuck here.

       How do I intercept the incoming record and construct
       a single dynamic field based on
       `ParameterValue.parameter.[name, type, display_name, is_required, help_text]`?

       `Parameter.name` is the variable name for the form field
       `Parameter.type` determines what type of field it should be
       `Parameter.display_name` is what is label used on the form
       `Parameter.is_required` determines if the required property should be added to the field
       `Parameter.help_text` is passed as the "description" kwarg and rendered below the input
    """


class AccountView(ModelView):
    """
    I'm trying to create a single field per associated ParameterValue.
    """
    column_list = ("client_name", "username")
    form_columns = ("client_name", "username", "reporter_fields")
    inline_models = (ParameterInlineForm(ParameterValue),)


@app.before_first_request
def startup():
    db.create_all()
    rep = Reporter(module="test")
    param_str = Parameter(name="string", type="str", display_name="String Field", is_required=True,
                          help_text="Enter a string", reporter=rep)
    param_int = Parameter(name="integer", type="int", display_name="Integer Field", reporter=rep)
    param_bool = Parameter(name="boolean", type="bool", display_name="Boolean Field", reporter=rep)
    param_list = Parameter(name="alist", type="list", display_name="Tag Field", reporter=rep)
    act = Account(
        client_name="John Doe",
        username="jd123",
        reporter=rep,
        reporter_fields=[
            ParameterValue(parameter=param_str, value="I'm a string"),
            ParameterValue(parameter=param_bool, value=True)
        ]
    )
    db.session.add_all([rep, param_str, param_int, param_bool, param_list, act])
    db.session.commit()


admin = Admin(app, url="/", template_mode="bootstrap4")
admin.add_view(AccountView(Account, db.session, name="Accounts", endpoint="accounts"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```